# Drop down for a single element in a loop based on an id in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and have an app that displays some data. I am using a map function to build one component multiple times. When a button is clicked inside of an element more data should be displayed but only in the clicked element. Currently, when I click a button in one element can toggle the display of the additional data for all element as well as store the unique id of the clicked element in a state. I am pretty sure that I need to filter the results and I have seen similar examples but I can't say that I fully understand them. Any tips or more beginner-friendly tutorials are greatly appreciated.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import '../style/skeleton.css'
import '../style/style.css'

export default function Body( student ) {
    const [active, setActive] = useState({
        activeStudent: null,
    });

    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (display === false) {
            setDisplay(true)
        } else {
            setDisplay(false)
        }
    }, [active])

    const handleClick = (id) => setActive({ activeStudent: id});


    return (
        <div>
            {student.student.map((data) => {
                const id = data.id;
                return (
                <div key={data.id} className="row border">
                    <div className="two-thirds column">
                        <h3>{data.firstName} {data.lastName}</h3>
                        { display ? 
                        <button onClick={() => handleClick(id)}>-</button> 
                        :
                        <button  onClick={() => handleClick(id)}>+</button> }
                       { display ? <div>
                           <p>{data.addional} additonal data</p>
                       </div> : null }
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `active.activeStudent === id ?` instead of `display ? `?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from:

```
{ display ? <div><p>{data.addional} additonal data</p></div> : null }
```

To:

```
{ active.activeStudent === id ? <div><p>{data.addional} additonal data</p></div> : null }
```